# Dynamics CRM Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I wish to use Reflection inside a Dynamics CRM Online plugin. I am aware that CRM Online uses a Medium-Trust environment, which does not allow Reflection. However, I also understand that Reflection within the same assembly *is* permitted - since it's within the same assembly, which can automatically trust itself.

Note that my CRM plugin solution contains several projects - therefore several DLLs *outside CRM*, but I'm using ILMerge to merge these together into 1 assembly for deployment to CRM. Therefore, this single assembly contains several different namespaces, however for the purposes of Reflection permissions this is just one assembly with different namespaces in it - nothing unusual about that, and should not cause reflection issue problems - AFAIK.

In my local testing environment, I have used https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/PartialTrustExample to setup a partial trust environment and to test my Reflection. In this testing environment, the assemblies are not merged with ILMerge but using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute I'm able to successfully do Reflection. The `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute stays there in the assembly which is the result of the ILMerge, but actually is not required since ILMerge creates just the one assembly.

This is the error that CRM is giving me:

```
Attempt by method 'Namespace1.QueryProvider.Evaluator+SubtreeEvaluator.GetValue(System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)' to access field 'Namespace2.Entities.CreditTransaction+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.id' failed.: at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.PerformVisibilityCheckOnField(IntPtr field, Object target, RuntimeType declaringType, FieldAttributes attr, UInt32 invocationFlags)
at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)
at Namespace1.QueryProvider.Evaluator.SubtreeEvaluator.GetValue(MemberExpression exp)
```

The method Namespace1.QueryProvider.Evaluator+SubtreeEvaluator.GetValue(System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression) does this:

```
private object GetValue(MemberExpression exp)
{
    if (exp.Expression is ConstantExpression)
    {
        return (((ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value).GetType().GetField(exp.Member.Name).GetValue(((ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value);
    }   
}
```

The field Namespace2.Entities.CreditTransaction+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.id is being passed in to the above method via the following expression and it refers to the id variable which from my reading is defined as internal by the compiler as part of the ClosureExpression:

```
Guid id = newTrans.Account.Id;
List<CreditTransaction> transactions = context.CreditTransactionSet.Where(ct => ct.Account.Id == id).OrderByDescending(ct => ct.CreatedOn).ToList();
```

Can anyone shed any light on this for me as to why it's not working (ie. a gap in my knowledge), or steer me towards a solution if my working theory is correct that reflection within the same assembly should be possible despite the trust environment?

Comment: Have you definitely ruled out ILMerge as a possible error source? That is, in your limited trust test environment, have you also run tests with ILMerge-d assemblies (instead of `[InternalsVisibleTo]`)?

Comment: @stakx, I haven't done that no, immediately it's impossible since I can't run tests on my ILMerge'd assembly as I get errors because of duplicate declarations - both in the seperate dll produced by the project within the solution, and for the copy of that dll inside the ILMerge'd assembly. However, the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute *has* to be ignored in the ILMerge'd context, since there is no seperate assembly to specify that the the Internals should be visible to - all internals are contained within the *same* assembly. Therefore, I'm not sure how that could be relevant?

Comment: I guess that in theory, you're right. In practice? I don't know. But you're saying that you're getting errors with the ILMerge'd assembly. Yet you expect it to work flawlessly. If I were you, I'd first remove known errors before I chase a hard-to-catch bug. Could be that these things *are* related. -- That being said, I guess it's worth remembering that ILMerge is an old tool that was written before .NET 4. AFAIK it is no longer updated, nor maintained. See also what its creator wrote about it [here](http://simoneb.github.io/blog/2011/11/21/past-present-and-future-of-net-assembly-merging/).

Comment: Hi @stakx, I've gone as far as I can in terms of testing the ILMerged plugin assembly. I setup a new test project, linked it to the ILMerged assembly and ran code through the same code which the plugin is calling - this required an internal of the testing assembly to be processed by the same GetValue method referenced in my question above. I ran the test in a PartialTrust environment, and there was NO `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in the test assembly - however everything worked fine.